# Manage groovy dependencies in Java

Tags: java, groovy, dependencies

I'm working on a Java motor to run Groovy Scripts, I want to load all the dependencies needed to run a Groovy script. At the moment, I'm loading jars as bellow :

```
        File file = new File(elem);

        URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
        URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        try {
            cl.loadClass("com.example.ScriptLibrary");
            return cl;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new MalformedURLException("[Error] : Bad library path\n");
        }
```

It works so my code loads jar libraries. I wanted to know if there is an other way for Groovy dependencies or I can do like it and load jars as I do for a Java code.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the Groovy script engine support built into Java? Groovy is extra syntax and functionality on top of Java so the dependencies work the same.

Comment: Yes because scripts can change and I will get them from a database with their environment so I have to load all dependencies necessary to run the script

Comment: I am pretty sure that the Grab/Grape dependency management (Groovy) works when run inside the script engine. Then your scripts can each define the dependencies they need.

Comment: Ok thanks I will take a look on that :)

Comment: If you use the standard ScriptEngine (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) it should just work. You should look into the Groovy implementation of the Java ScriptEngine. Also, probably a non-native speaker issue, but you probably want to use "engine" rather than "motor" in this case.

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html So if I use grape, I have to manage my dependencies in the script itself ? Or it stills in Java ?